# python3 appropriate way to interrupt multi-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm writing a multi-thread web crawler, the routine function for each thread is basically a endless loop, and there is a shared dictionary to store those url which have already been accessed, and I use a thread lock to synchronize.

I might want to interrupt it with ctrl+c sometimes, I add a try catch in thread run function to catch keyboard interrupt, and after that I might want to do some finalizing task for example dumping data to database or pkl file.

The problem is that each time I interrupt it, it just can not get into the catch process, sometimes it just stuck there, and sometimes it still keep running.

So what might be the best practice to handle exception/interrupt in multi thread programming?

I put my code as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import threading
import queue
import pickle
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

worker_num = 8
q = queue.Queue()
lock = threading.Lock()

if os.path.exists('./checked.pkl'):
    with open('./checked.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        checked = pickle.load(f)
else:
    checked = set()


def get_links(url):
    # do sth....


def run():
    print(threading.current_thread())
    try:
        while True:
            next_url = q.get()
            links = get_links(next_url)
            lock.acquire()
            for link in links:
                if link not in checked:
                    q.put(link)
            print(len(checked))
            lock.release()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('interrupt')
        lock.acquire()
        with open('./checked.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(checked, f)
        lock.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q.put(start_url)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(worker_num) as executor:
        for _ in range(worker_num):
            executor.submit(run)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyboardInterrupt` is always raised in the main thread.  You cannot handle it in another thread.

You should checkpoint your state after each successful chunk of work (it doesn't have to be after each URL but it might as well be).  This will give you state updates even if your process crashes for another reason (some unhandleable reason - like a segfault or if the whole host crashes).  You should also write your checkpoint atomically so that if you crash mid-update you don't end up with corrupt, unusable state.  (You should also not use pickle as your checkpoint state format due to its insecurity, fragility, and cross-language challenges.)

Once your state updates are being written safely and periodically during normal operation, you can make the crawler interruptable by making the worker threads into *daemon threads* and adding `KeyboardInterrupt` handling to the main thread.  At this point, it won't matter if the worker threads are killed without a chance for cleanup (as will happen if you make them daemon threads and let the main thread exit) because they will have checkpointed their state recently.

Also, you should consider using an existing crawling tool like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) instead of rolling your own.